# Another couple of doozies: 許臣時一中之... and 敢不勉增淸烈。益播芳芬。

Tags: classical-chinese, traditional-characters, literature

Ok folks, I have another asshole section from the text I am working on, Suseongji (Chouchengzhi), by a 16th century Joseon literatus...

This time, this passage is driving me nuts:

攻愁有方。許臣時一中之。不疑於用。謂臣招衆口。爾獨斷於心。遂令薄才。得容海量。敢不勉增淸烈。益播芳芬。杯酒釋兵權。

The only bit that is really clear to me is 杯酒釋兵權。but the general context is that a General Malt (e.g. alcohol) is addressing the 天君 (e.g. the mind) so maybe there are some jokes I don't understand...?

'There is a method for attacking/defeating/overcoming sorrows. Permit me to pick a time and at once go inside of it [the Citadel of Sorrows] (許臣時一中之), and “do not doubt those you use” (不疑於用). This is to say that though I have been much-criticised (謂臣招衆口), you alone made the judgement [about me] in your mind. It follows that when you order someone of inferior talent to contain the ocean (i.e. do as much as they can), they are so daring/presumptuous that they do not strive...增淸烈。益播芳芬。'

If anyone can help with this I will be so so grateful.

Comment: IMHO this article was quite terrible. I can't see much original language other than bulk text citing or quoting other works.

Comment: You mean my post?

Comment: no, I meant Suseongji (Chouchengzhi).

Comment: Ahahaha my bad I thought maybe I am using this site wrong! Yes, it is an annoying work and I am finding it annoying and really hard to translate. I wouldn't have picked it if I'd read the whole thing before I started my program. My basic thesis now is that it is not an 'original novel'...it is not original, or a novel...it is a LOT of allusions all mashed up together...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

海量 is a pun; a man with the ability to accept others' opinions, and someone who can hold as much liquor as you can pour into him.
淸烈 also, 'purity of heart' and 'strong white (distilled?) liquor'
芳芬 also, 'fragrance = a great reputation' and fragrance = 'well fermented booze'

Comment: This whole text is too punny for my liking...